# Simple OrderBy not working?

Tags: linq-to-entities

For the life of me I can figure out why my OrderBy is not working here. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
var result = (from a in AUDIT
                join e in EMPLOYEE on a.KEY equals e.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
                join j in JOB on e.JOB_CODE equals j.JOB_CODE 
                where a.AUDIT_TYPE == "JUMPSEAT" 
                    && a.TRANSMIT_DATE == null 
                    && a.CO == e.CO 
                    && a.KEY == e.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER 
                orderby e.SHARP_NUMBER
                select new
                {
                    SharpNumber = e.SHARP_NUMBER,
                }).Distinct().ToList();

result.Dump();
```

**UPDATE**
It has something to do with the .Distinct(). If I remove that it seems to do the order by but that also causes extra records. Anyone know how to work an orderby in a distinct?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Use the column in the Object and not the table column.

```
.Distinct().OrderBy(o => o.SharpNumber).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

relation database is hard to scale, more easy add additional front end/middle tier,
so when you will have bigger table and wants all data, better way not sort directly in database, but in front end/middle tier.

So now you will get distinct data from server and in .net will sort results.

`Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(o => o.SharpNumber);`

Answer (score 0):

actually problem is in you code you first ordering then creating object. then distinct then list.

so problem is first it get sorted then create the object so we can have hope object collection is also sorted. but when u used distinct. all go messed up.. then u created the list of messed up.. :( boom....

> so first create object > then distinct > then order.

```
var result = (from a in AUDIT
            join e in EMPLOYEE on a.KEY equals e.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
            join j in JOB on e.JOB_CODE equals j.JOB_CODE 
            where a.AUDIT_TYPE == "JUMPSEAT" 
                && a.TRANSMIT_DATE == null 
                && a.CO == e.CO 
                && a.KEY == e.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER 
            select new
            {
                SharpNumber = e.SHARP_NUMBER,
            }).Distinct()
              .OrderBy(c=>c.SharpNumber)
              .ToList();
```